# Managed Account Generate New Password Caused Search to fail

Tags: search, managed-account

I used the managed account generate new password for my search service account. Everything looks like it worked just fine but now I'm getting ***Item was not crawled because of a password change. Update password and retry crawling***. I retrieved the password using powershell and attempted to change it in the search administration page but it tells me my password is incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me its looks like a bad password, that's why i hate SharePoint Managed account's ability to generate new password.

What i would do.

- Change the password of Default content Access Account( Manually change it)
- Update the Search adminsitration with new password
- Update the Account under the managed account.

Comment: Thanks, I used powershell to retrieve the password then had my AD admin update the password in AD